# NGINX Load Balancer: [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "server.two:8088" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/alb.conf:27

Tags: docker, nginx, load, load-balancing, upstream

Trying to build simple example of using NGINX as a load balancer,
i am getting the error when starting:

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "server.two:8088" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/alb.conf:27
```

I know that this issue can be related to the server which is not running when the upstream is upping.

So my question is -- Is there solution on how to run NGINX servers before upstream is upping?
Or is there any solution how it can be fixed in other way?

My env is:

- Win 10
- WSL2
- Docker

`docker-compose.yml` contains:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: nginx:1.25.2
    container_name: "load_balancer_nginx"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ../src/:/var/www/html:rw
      - ../nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ../nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ../nginx/alb.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/alb.conf # Application Load Balancer
```

`alb.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name server.one;
    root /var/www/html/server.one/;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
server {
    listen 8088;
    server_name server.two;
    root /var/www/html/server.two/;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
upstream all {
    server server.one:8000;
    server server.two:8088;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name magento_alb.loc;
    absolute_redirect off;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://all/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
```

`default.conf`:

```
#nothing. just to rewrite the existing one.
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
events {}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

a) Trying to start docker container without errors,
But i am facing with errors.

b) have tried to use the variable but also without any success( still getting the same error )
set $backend_servers all;
proxy_pass http://$backend_servers;

c) have tried to use the map -- no success ( i am getting the same error )
map $scheme $server_two {
default server.two:8088;
}
upstream all {
server server.one:8000;
server $server_two;
}

d) Used the `fail_timeout & max_fails` -- the same error
upstream all {
server server.one:8000 fail_timeout=999s max_fails=999999;
server server.two:8088 fail_timeout=999s max_fails=999999;
}